# Retrieve images from storage with the help of path saved in database and display in listView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-database

I have seen many and many other questions related to this but none of them helped.

I have  a table "item_table" stored in database in which there are 3 columns, 'ITEM','CATEGORY','IMAGE_PATH' and 'PRICE'.

I'm able to save path in the DB (the path is of the images that are stored in SDCard)

.On an activity i have a spinner. when a category is selected from spinner, the listview should display items , price and images from storage using the path of that item's image.
This is my adapter class.

CustomListAdapter.Java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {


public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
    super(context, layout, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView itemName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemName_lbl);
    String name_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item"));
    int resIdName = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name_string,"string",context.getPackageName());
    itemName.setText(resIdName);

    TextView price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price_lbl);
    String price_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("price"));
    int resPriceName = context.getResources().getIdentifier(price_string,"string",context.getPackageName());
    price.setText(resPriceName);

}
}
```

This is the code for getting itemName and price.

```
 public Cursor getList () {
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String s = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String[] select = {"_id","item","price"};
    String table = "item_table";
    String where = "category = '"+s+"' ";

    qb.setTables(table);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db,select,where,null,null,null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    return c;
}
```

With this i'm able to get the name and price of item, but i can't get images of those items with the help of path.

This is what i've tried so far.

```
 ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
    {
    String spinnerCategory = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT image_path from item_table where category = '"+spinnerCategory+"' ";
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                images.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }

        File imgFile = new File(String.valueOf(images));
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(images));
            //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage_icon);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
    }
```

But this changes nothing in the listview. PLease please help me.
If any edit is to be done in the question tell me.
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your getList() method

```
public Cursor getList () {
SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

String s = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

String[] select = {"_id","item","price","image_path"};
String table = "item_table";
String where = "category = '"+s+"' ";

qb.setTables(table);
Cursor c = qb.query(db,select,where,null,null,null,null);
c.moveToFirst();

return c;
}
```

update your adapter

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

TextView itemName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemName_lbl);
String name_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item"));
int resIdName = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name_string,"string",context.getPackageName());
itemName.setText(resIdName);

TextView price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price_lbl);
String price_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("price"));
int resPriceName = context.getResources().getIdentifier(price_string,"string",context.getPackageName());
price.setText(resPriceName);

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage_icon);
String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image_path"));
Glide.with(context).load(filePath).into(myImage);

}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit. i dont know how to use it.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1091/glide#t=201611151222582060503

Comment: Sir, i can't get exact solution. As i don't have a single path or image. I have multipple paths and i need to retrieve multiple images through their paths and display in listview.

Comment: set your images from your adapter

Comment: But how can i create an adapter of paths to get all images?